# How to create SharingReason with Metadata API?

Tags: metadata-api

I'm trying to create Sharing Reason Dynamically with Metadata API. All the tutorials online show me how to do with Custom Object and Custom Field but I would like to know the specific steps required.

Comment: I'm stuck on referencing the object that sharing reason pertains to. Do I need to create a Metadata.CustomObject then add the list of sharing reasons there? Will it update and removed existing fields on the object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this?
[Sharing a Record Using Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm)

Comment: This does not work dynamically, you would have to create the labels first